# Why GROUP BY is needed for a nested aggregate function in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table named SHIP_CABINS and its structure is like this:

```
Name          Null?    Type         
------------- -------- ------------ 
SHIP_CABIN_ID NOT NULL NUMBER       
ROOM_NUMBER            NUMBER       
TYPE                   VARCHAR2(10) 
SQ_FT                  NUMBER
```

I can issue the following queries without using a GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT MAX(SQ_FT)
FROM SHIP_CABINS;

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM SHIP_CABINS;
```

However, if I nest MAX and COUNT function, I have to use a GROUP BY clause. The following query will fail:

```
SELECT MAX(COUNT(*))
FROM SHIP_CABINS;
```

If my table contains 10 rows, why does the above query run without a GROUP BY clause and simple returns 10?

Comment: I'm confused.  Does the query fail?  And that is your question?  Or does the query run and simply return 10?

Comment: Think about it: How does it know what to group by? In the first version, both are computed over the empty set (the whole table), and only return a single row. Now it would appear you want the max of a single value: the total count, which doesn't make sense

Comment: @Charlieface: The MAX of a single value seems to be working: SELECT MAX(1) FROM SHIP_CABINS;

Comment: Huh, that returns the value `1` always, as for every row you are taking the max of the value `1`

Comment: @GordonLinoff - the query fails with the error message saying that a nested aggregate function requires a `group by` clause. Not 100% explicit in the OP's question, but I would say at least 95%. And his question, pretty clearly, is "why does that constraint exist".

Comment: @Charlieface - The queries are not computed over the "empty set". They are computed grouped by an empty set of `columns`, which is quite different; the "set" over which the aggregates are computed is the set of `rows` in the table. As to your second comment, why does it not make sense to take the MAX of a single number? It makes perfect sense. It may be somewhat wasteful (we know the answer is that one number), but why doesn't it make sense?

Comment: @mathguy . . . You are missing the point.  The question is quite unclear.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Please read the posts more closely before making comments like that. Can't you find the following in the original post? "***The following query will fail:***" It's been there in the original post from the beginning.

Comment: "If my table contains 10 rows, why does the above query run without a GROUP BY clause and simple returns 10?"

Comment: @mathguy Sorry, apologies for not being clear, in a grouping there is a specific term called the "empty set" `()` which refers to columns as you say. `MAX(1)` works, but makes no sense in terms of "why would you read a whole table to return the value "1 it's not actually aggregating anything and you may as well do `select 1`. In your own answer, `max(count(*)) over ()` without a `group by` is nonsensical for a similar reason: we can just write `select count(*)` and get the same result. You **need** a double grouping (or windowing function) otherwise there's no way to tell how to group

Comment: @Charlieface - There **is** a way to tell how to group. We may agree that it's not very rational (there is no obvious reason one would ever **want** to group that way), but the way is quite simple: the inner aggregation is over the entire table; the outer aggregation is over one row (and therefore it doesn't do anything - but that doesn't mean that it is logically invalid).

Comment: @mathguy I suppose since nested aggregation is ambiguous in the general case, and here it makes no sense even if unambiguous, the language designers saw no reason to allow it in this special case.

Comment: **FUN POP-QUIZ** for all participants in this discussion: What is the result of `select count(count(*)) from dual where 0 = 1 group by 'x';` - and, rather, ***why***? Work through it in two steps: what is the result of the nested aggregation alone? Hint: the full explanation is essentially the first paragraph in my answer. It's a fun exercise to understand what happens at each of the two steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the error message you get says it `ORA-00978: nested group function without GROUP BY`

If you check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Aggregate-Functions.html#GUID-62BE676B-AF18-4E63-BD14-25206FEA0848) there is not an explicit notion of this limitation, but *carefully reading* the description of the functionality you should realize, that the `Group by`clause **is required** for the usage of the nested aggregate functions.

> You can nest aggregate functions  ...
> This calculation evaluates the inner aggregate (MAX(salary)) for each group **defined by the GROUP BY** clause ...,
> and aggregates the results again.

So you have two workarounds to *simulate* the **nested aggregation without GROUP BY**

A) Add constant `GROUP BY`

```
select max(count(*)) from tab group by 42;
```

Note that you must use `NLV` if you require a *zero* result on the empty table (same as in case B)

```
select nvl(max(count(*)),0) max_cnt from tab group by 42
```

B) Split in two Subqueries

```
with tab2 as (
select count(*) cnt from tab)
select max(cnt) max_cnt
from tab2
```

Comment: The first solution is not equivalent to "nested aggregation without `group by`" - specifically when the base table is empty (or there is a `with` clause that filters out all the rows). Consider for example an empty table `t`. `select count(*) from t` returns one row, with the value 0. `select count(*) from t group by 42` returns no rows. So, if you apply `count(count(*))` to the latter query, the result will be 0. You can't really apply it to the first query (that's exactly what the OP is asking about), but if you could, the answer **should** be 1, because the nested query returns one row.

Comment: You are right @mathguy if the table is empty only the case B) applies

Answer (score 1):

First note that simply selecting an aggregate like `count(*)` with no `group by` clause is not always equivalent to aggregating over all the rows in the table. Namely, the only exception is when the table is empty (or the query includes a `where` clause that filters out all the rows). With `group by 'x'` (or some other constant that guarantees that all rows are in a single group - I personally like `group by null`) the query returns no rows, because there are no groups. **Without** a `group by` clause, however, the aggregate query **does** return a row - it will show `count(*)` of 0, for example. Try to remember this when you use aggregate functions without `group by` and you start seeing odd results.

Now back to your question. There is no logical reason Oracle (or the SQL standard) can't allow nested aggregate functions without `group by`. Let the inner function be calculated over the base table, and the outer aggregate be calculated over the result set of the first aggregation. Why Oracle chose not to allow it is a good question for Oracle.

However, if for some reason you must do what you showed, you can change the `max()` call from an aggregate function to an analytic function, as shown below. The inner aggregation always returns exactly one row (even when the base table is empty, or there is a `where` clause that filters out all the rows), so the "analytic function" is over a single row - there is no performance hit.

```
select max(count(*)) over ()       -- notice the (empty!) analytic clause
from   ship_cabins;
```

Comment: But without a `group by` it makes no sense. You may as well return `count(*)` it will be exactly the same. And if you add a `group by`, you get the same value again and again for every grouping

Comment: @Charlieface - **Why** the OP would want to do what he described, I don't know - that is a question of logic, not of programming. He asked why the syntax rules don't allow him to do it (regardless of whether what he is trying to do is reasonable or not; **logically** it is perfectly valid). I am not saying that what the OP is doing is rational - who knows what reasons he has. Perhaps his real-life case is much more complex and perhaps something like this does make sense.

Comment: But anyway, that is not what he asked. We can certainly take MAX over a single row in Oracle; why not be able to do it over the result of the nested aggregation, which always returns one row? There is no general rule that prevents us from aggregating over a single row, is there? Why is there one in this special case?

Comment: Ok, I suppose. But I generally like to answer the underlying problem rather than just the specific way OP has put it. To each their own, your code is valid technically.